# Duplicates in leaderboards/achievements after publishing second game services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have one simple game in Google Play published as Alpha and I have come across this problem. There are two game services published within my account - one for testing purposes that is now unpublished and one with real leaderboards/achievements that I would like to keep.

The problem is that in the application after I changed client ID to reflect current services I can still see old leaderboards from unpublished game services along with real ones from published game services.

Is there something I can do to remove/clear those obsolete leaderboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be some "cache" problem on Google Play side. After an hour the old leaderboards and achievements were removed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If the game is unpublished, then you should be able to delete your game from the "6. publishing your game" section. Better still, you can just delete your leaderboard from "4. Leaderboards".

Comment: I know, but I had been creating game services for the game that was already signed and published as alpha so I had to publish those game services as well. (Which was not probably a good idea)

Comment: This video is a good resource and, if I remember correctly, highlights the fact that (because of the nature of the Google backend) it takes a while (they say sometimes hours) for some changes to propagate: https://developers.google.com/live/shows/5936979195723776